# Bokeh: add a % sign to axis ticks without changing numeric value

Tags: python, formatting, bokeh

I am creating a plot in Bokeh with percentages on the y-axis. The data is represented as a percent (e.g. '99.0') as opposed to a likelihood (e.g. '0.990'). I want to add a '%' sign after each number on the axis, but when using `NumeralTickFormatter(format='0 %')` my values are multiplied by 100 because it expects a likelihood. I don't want to change the data representation to a likelihood, so is there some other way I can get the '%' sign to appear on the axis ticks?

Comment: What about `PrintfTickFormatter`? http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#printftickformatter

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on what bigreddot proposed: `PrintfTickFormatter(format='%0.0f %%')` worked. One thing to note is the `%%` to properly escape the %.